# Uploading Google App Engine Project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

I am trying to upload various App Engine projects with appcfg.py, both with PyCharm and Terminal.

I have been developing on PyCharm for over a year and have never had an issue uploading apps.

This began a couple of weeks ago, when I added a new project and tried to upload with oAuth2 activated.

I receive the following error message in PyCharm:

"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0\bin\runnerw.exe"

C:\Python27\python.exe

"C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py"

update "..:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\MyApp"

08:58 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update  | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Not a directory: ..:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects

---

In Terminal I receive the exact same error message.

I have been in touch with PyCharm support, and while very helpful, they claim that this error, as it is replicated in Terminal, is nothing to do with PyCharm.

What could be causing this error? And how to fix it?

Point of interest:

The error was the same in PyCharm 4.5 as it is in 5.0 so it's not the new release. I tried a clean install, keeping no settings from 4.5. The error now affects all 4 apps I have in production/development, not only the new one that was added a couple of weeks ago.
The error before the clean install was the same, except that the root app folder was not a directory. While now the Pycharm Projects folder is not a directory.

i.e.

Previously: ..\Me\PyCharmProjects\My App -> not a directory.

Now: ..\Me\PyCharmProjects -> not a directory.

Thanks, I hope that's enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: Why does your directory path start with `..:\`? Is that normal?

Comment: same here... can't solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the `..:`, thats not a path. On the commandline you should be runnig

```
c:/Python27/python.exe "C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py" update c:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/MyApp
```

Comment: Hi. The "..." was just shorthand, and me being lazy to write out the full path here. However, the answer is that the path to the project folder needs to be complete. i.e. update "C:/Users/Me/PyCharmProjects/myapp". That works in terminal even though it still throws an error in Pycharm. This is now a known issue in Pycharm 5.0 and hopefully will be solved soon. Thanks.